# Periodic check for data posted from 3rd Party app in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redis

3rd Party application posts regular/triggered updates to a redis database as a `list`.

Laravel application needs to periodically check in the redis and if there's data, further processing will be done. Can someone suggest the best way of doing this in laravel (5.7*).

Comment: can you specify how regular that should occur? Usually you'd just set up a job

Comment: once every 10 mins or so.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a command and using the task scheduler. Laravel already has included a way to connect your application to Redis.

You can find more information about the task scheduler in [the Laravel documentation on task scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling). Please note that you have to add the scheduler to your server's cronlist. Laravel also provides [documentation about their Redis implementation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/redis).

Sidenote:
As task scheduling can lead to certain instabilities, especially if your server has had some downtime and you have to check the database at a certain set time, I would recommend considering using a webhook to trigger Laravel checking the Redis-database. Using a multi-server environment also becomes a lot less painful this way.